# How to declare AppComponent in two different modules

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running Angular 7 project which contains two different applications:

1. BasicTools
2. AdvancedTools

BasicTools project points to basic-main.ts and AdvancedTools project points to advanced-main.ts. From basic-main.ts file, BasicAppModule is bootstraped and from advanced-main.ts AdvancedAppModule is bootstraped.

I have common AppComponent which is being used in both BasicAppModule and AdvancedAppModule but while building the application, I am getting error as AppComponent is declared as part of two module.

I tried exporting AppComponent in basic-app.module.ts and also removed the declaration of AppComponent from advanced-app.module.ts but getting error as: AppComponent should be declared as part of ngModule.

Is there any way to fix this as I need AppComponent in both the modules.??

Below is my angular.json file:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "BasicTools": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "Client",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot",
            "index": "Client/index.html",
            "main": "Client/app/basic/basic-main.ts",
            "polyfills": "Client/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "Client/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "Client/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "Client/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "Client/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "Client/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "BasicTools:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "BasicTools:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
    },
    "AdvancedTools": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "Client",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "styleext": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "wwwroot",
            "index": "Client/index.html",
            "main": "Client/app/advanced/advanced-main.ts",
            "polyfills": "Client/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "Client/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "Client/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "Client/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "Client/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "Client/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "none",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "AdvancedTools:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "AdvancedTools:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
    },
```

advanced-main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { AdvancedAppModule } from '../advanced-app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AdvancedAppModule);
```

basic-main.ts

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { BasicAppModule } from '../basic-app.module';

if (environment.production) {
  enableProdMode();
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(BasicAppModule);
```

advanced-app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    BasicModule,
    AdvancedModule,
    applicationRoutingInformation
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: MiPathLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AdvancedAppModule { }
```

basic-app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BasicModule,
    CoreModule,
    SharedModule,
    applicationRoutingInformation
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: MiPathLocationStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class BasicAppModule { }
```

Comment: create a `shared module` and add the `app component` to that module ( where it will be exported ) and then import the `shared module` to the respective modules you need

Answer (score 1):

Create `AppModule` that exports `AppComponent` and import it in both of your root module configurations:

*app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  exports: [AppComponent]
})
export AppModule {}
```

*basic-app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  ...
})
export class BasicAppModule{}
```

*advanced-app.module.ts*

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [AppModule, ...],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  ...
})
export class AdvancedAppModule {}
```

Even further if you have some common dependencies for you AppComponent shared between those two entry modules you can add providers for them in `AppModule` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We can't declare same component in two different and in this case we create a common module  and imports it to both of modules.

```
common-module.ts

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
//import your component


@NgModule({
  declarations:[yourComponent],
  exports: [yourComponent]
})

export class CommonModule { }
```